# Optimizing a query which runs through all hours in a day

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I need help optimizing a query. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.4 currently but can upgrade to 9.4 if needed.

I have a table with 60+ millions of records which looks like this:

```
                                                          Table "public.snapshots"
   Column   |           Type           |                         Modifiers                          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('snapshots_new_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 camera_id  | integer                  | not null                                                   | plain    |              | 
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                   | plain    |              | 
 notes      | text                     |                                                            | extended |              | 
 data       | bytea                    | not null                                                   | extended |              | 
 is_public  | boolean                  | not null default false                                     | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "snapshots_new_created_at_camera_id_index" UNIQUE, btree (created_at, camera_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "snapshots_new_camera_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (camera_id) REFERENCES cameras(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

There can be between 0 and 3600 snapshot records in an hour. For this query I'm interested only in knowing which hours in a given day for a given `camera_id` have 1 or more snapshot records (the actual count is unimportant).

Currently the application is implemented to execute one query for each hour in the day, like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "snapshots" WHERE (("snapshots"."camera_id" = 4809) AND ("created_at" >= '2015-05-24 23:00:00 UTC') AND ("created_at" <= '2015-05-24 23:59:59 UTC'));
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "snapshots" WHERE (("snapshots"."camera_id" = 4809) AND ("created_at" >= '2015-05-25 00:00:00 UTC') AND ("created_at" <= '2015-05-25 00:59:59 UTC'));
...
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "snapshots" WHERE (("snapshots"."camera_id" = 4809) AND ("created_at" >= '2015-05-25 22:00:00 UTC') AND ("created_at" <= '2015-05-25 22:59:59 UTC'));
```

> Explain analyze for one query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/9tbP

I tried optimizing this and ended up with one query which seemed like it was what I needed:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "snapshots" WHERE (("created_at" > '2015-05-06 23:00:00.000000+0000') AND ("created_at" < '2015-05-08 23:00:00.000000+0000')) GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', created_at);
```

> Explain analyze for this query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/cVUK

But this is actually 10x times slower than the above 24 queries combined.

What am I doing wrong? Should I forget `COUNT` since I'm not interested in the actual count? How would the query look like then?

**Edit:** Thanks for all the comments and answers, I learned multiple things from you! I wish I could accept all three answers, I chose ypercube's as it seems most efficient and flexible.

Comment: Are you simply trying to get a list of hours that have more than zero snapshots?

Comment: Or are you trying to get a list of cameras with more than zero snapshots in a day?  Your requirements are unclear.

Comment: @MaxVernon Sorry, I thought it was clear from the question. I'm trying to get a list of hours which have more than zero snapshots with a given `camera_id` in a given day.

Comment: Do you have a multi-column index on camera_id and created_at?  I'm on my phone now, so it is difficult to be in-depth :-(

Comment: @Jack your grouping query does not have condition on camera_id, so it may read and process more records. And your datetime value has different format, but I am not using pg, so don't know if that can make any difference.

Comment: If the actual count is of no interest to you, you can do "SELECT 1 as has_row ..." to let optimizer maybe use some trick, but probably it won't change much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on [@Akash's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103287/optimizing-a-query-which-runs-through-all-hours-in-a-day/103361#103361) which uses the `LATERAL` syntax and results in a better execution plan (check the `Index Only Scan using idx2_snapshots on snapshots` in the plan below):

```
SELECT 
      hour AS start_hour,
      hour + interval '1 hour' AS end_hour
FROM 
      generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, 
                      '2015-01-02 23:00:00'::timestamp, 
                      '1 hour') AS hour 
    , LATERAL
        ( SELECT 1 
          FROM snapshots 
          WHERE camera_id = 3 
            AND created_at >= hour 
            AND created_at < hour + interval '1 hour' 
          LIMIT 1 
        ) AS x ;
```

Tested in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d041/9) (query 2). The plan:

```
Nested Loop (cost=0.43..4083.77 rows=1000 width=8)
-> Function Scan on generate_series hour (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8)
-> Limit (cost=0.43..4.05 rows=1 width=0)
-> Index Only Scan using idx2_snapshots on snapshots (cost=0.43..7740.98 rows=2139 width=0)
Index Cond: ((camera_id = 3) AND (created_at >= hour.hour) AND (created_at < (hour.hour + '01:00:00'::interval)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea: create a table with all hours in the day (0-23).

```
create table hours(
  hr integer
);
```

Then find all hours that have snapshots for the given camera_id and date (of course, you will need to substitute your own camera_id and date into the query):

```
select h.hr, 1 as camera_id
from hours h
where exists (
    select 1 
    from snapshots s
    where s.camera_id = 1
    and s.created_at between to_timestamp ('2015-05-01 ' || to_char(h.hr, '00') || ':00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                             and to_timestamp ('2015-05-01 ' || to_char(h.hr, '00') || ':59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
)
```

See this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b88ce/1). To return a count(*) from the table the database has to go through all the rows that satisfy the condition to count them; exists() should limit this to finding the first row that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 3):

I tried creating a small [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d041/2) of your database, we should probably force the planner to use a `semi-join` nested loop which would **stop processing** further rows as soon as it finds the first row for a given `hour, camera_id` as zugguy suggested.

You can have a workaround with the temporary table using `generate_series` to get hours for the given datetimes.

```
SELECT 
  start_hour,
  end_hour
FROM
  (SELECT 
      hour as start_hour,
      hour + interval '1 hour' as end_hour
   FROM 
      generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-01-02 23:59:59'::timestamp, '1 hour') hour 
  ) as hours
WHERE
  EXISTS( SELECT 
            1 
          FROM 
          snapshots 
          WHERE
            camera_id = 3 
            AND created_at >= start_hour and created_at < end_hour )
```

[Plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/AZf), which takes `20 ms` for the sample database. **Notice** the sequence of columns within the `index` which plays a major factor. I have placed `camera_id` first, and then `created_at` under the assumption that the total no. of distinct values for `create_at` would be far greater than the total no. of `camera_ids` and **we want all the times for a given camera to be close** to each other within the index as that's our limiting factor.